# Readthedocs tries to build mkdocs project with sphinx

Tags: python, markdown, read-the-docs, mkdocs

I'm creating a python package for the first time and am having a lot of trouble getting my documentation to upload to readthedocs. I am using mkdocs to create my documentation. When I run the `mkdocs serve` command, my documentation loads just like I want it to. However, when I try to synchronize my project with readthedocs, I am met with a lot of trouble. The build is "successful", but I think it is being built as if it were created with sphinx (see screenshot of the build). I have done the following things:

- included a .readthedocs.yml file per the mkdocs readthedocs tutorial
- included a valid mkdocs.yml file
- set the documentation type to "Mkdocs" in the advanced settings

I can't think of another reason that this would be happening. Please let me know if you have any ideas. Thanks!

[Readthedocs Build Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLloL.png)

Comment: Check your project's build log for errors. Provide a reproducible example with code, preferably with a link to your repository. Else RTD: https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro/getting-started-with-mkdocs.html

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the build is working and passed, you might just need to remove your cache.